# gganimate along time series, not left to right

Tags: r, gganimate

I have made a `ggplot` line plot that uses two uses two sets of time series data and looks as it should as a static plot. Script and plot below:

```
p_curve <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
 geom_path(size = 1, colour = "red") +
 geom_path(x = Var3, y = Var4, size = 1, colour = "blue") +
 geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
 geom_hline(yintercept = Var2[1]) +
 xlim(c(min(df$Var1, df$Var3)), c(max(df$Var1, df$Var3))) +
 ylim(c(min(df$Var2, df$Var4)), c(max(df$Var2, df$Var4))) +
 theme_classic() +
 labs(x = "Variable", y = "Other Variable", title = "Variable x Variable Curve") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.5))
```

[image]

The plot looks exactly as it should. I would like to animate it so that it starts where the data starts (the middle of the curve, intersection of hline and vline) and then follows the time series. When I add `transition_reveal`, the plot animates from left to right in a wipe like fashion.

```
p_curve + transition_reveal(along = Var1)
```

Can anyone help with getting this to reveal along the data series, not the x-axis? Thanks in advance.